# Cakephp1.3 with PHP 8.1

Tags: cakephp-1.3, testcase, php-8.1

Can I upgrade PHP version 5.2 to PHP 8.1 with CakePHP 1.3?
What will be challenges during upgradation?
We need to to upgrade test cases too.

we want to run cakePHP 1.3 project with latest PHP version of server with out upgrading our cakephp version. that is our goal.

Comment: They certainly don't work together unchanged. It might be possible to make changes to the Cake 1.3 source to make it PHP 8 compatible, but it would be quite a lot of work, and probably nobody here will be able to direct you about what needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are a few developers who have done the work to update CakePHP 1.3 core files to make it work with PHP 8.1

Here's the repo: https://github.com/littleant/cakephp-1.3.21